# Writing multiple IF/AND functions

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, matching

I am trying to compare two spreadsheets. I want to match a NAME, DOB and a TYPE. I want all 3 to match to give me a "TRUE". 
I need to meet the following criteria:

(Matching names)- IF Sheet 1 Column D First 4 letters match AND Sheet 2 Column B First 4 letters match

If True, then

(Matching Dates)- IF Sheet 1 Column G matches to Sheet 2 Row 2

If both are true, then 
(THIS IS WHERE I GET STUCK)

Using the same matched name and date then match the First 3 letters of Sheet 1 Column J and Sheet 2 corresponding Row that was found to match the NAME(first criteria).

Thanks so much for any help! I'm seriously stumped!

Comment: If you're using excel, it would be helpful to tag it as such, as this would get the correct people to your question